Make document.visibilityState==='visible' using background.js in an extension
I want to keep a specific tab active even when I move to other tabs or other application.
I want to do this using an extension and only adding code to background.js.
Any ideas on how to do it?
console.log("background.js running");
// background console logs can be found by inspecting the extension in chrome://extensions > developer mode > then click on "service worker" > then go to console

Only the content script in the MAIN world can do it by overriding Document.prototype getter for visibilityState. You can inject it from the background script using chrome.scripting.executeScript.
